# WordPress fluent form is showing JSON when i first click on confirm registration shows json and then on reload it shows correct page

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using fluentform in wordpress for user registration with email confirmation, here is my confirmation settings.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBYGl.png)
With that i am using fluent form shortcodes for getting user data.

```
add_action('fluentform/user_registration_completed', function ($user_id, $feed, $entry, $form)
{
    log_to_browser_console('User registration completed', $entry);
    // Perform the GET request to the API endpoint with the user data
    $api_url = 'http://173.249.200.113:5000/api/account/create';


    $urlparts = wp_parse_url(home_url());
    $domain = $urlparts['host'];
    
    $user_inputs = $entry->user_inputs;
    $query_params = http_build_query([
        'first_name' => $user_inputs['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $user_inputs['last_name'],
        'email' => $user_inputs['email'],
        'age' => $user_inputs['age'],
        'state' => $user_inputs['state'],
        'team' => $user_inputs['team'],
        'api_key' => 'MY_API_KEY',
        'id' => $user_id,
        'website_id' => get_website_id(), 
    ]);
    $api_request_url = $api_url . '?' . $query_params;

    // Make the GET request to the API endpoint
    $response = wp_remote_get($api_request_url);

    

    // Process the API response if needed
    $redirect_url = get_home_url();
    // has_strava is a checkbox field and '1' is the value when it's checked
    if($user_inputs['has_strava'] == '1') { 
        // Redirect the user to the home page after successful registration
        $website_id_part= 'website_id=' . get_website_id();
        $redirect_url = 'http://173.249.200.113:5000/api/strava/auth?'.$website_id_part.'&api_key=MY_API_KEY&id=' . $user_id;

    }


    $response = [
        "success" => true,
        'data' => [
            'insert_id' => $entryId,
            'user_inputs'=> $user_inputs,
            'has_strava' => $user_inputs->has_strava,
            '$api_request_url' =>$api_request_url,
            'user_id' => $user_id, // Include the user ID in the response for the redirect
            'result' => [
                'redirectUrl' => $redirect_url, // Empty redirect URL as there's an error
                'message' => 'You have been registered successfully.',
                "action"=> "hide_form"
            ],
            'error' => ''
        ]
    ];
    log_to_browser_console("response ___", $response);
    wp_send_json($response);


}, 20, 4);



function custom_code_before_confirmation_msg_function($returnData, $form, $confirmation )
{  
    log_to_browser_console("confirmation ___", $confirmation);

    // get curretn user
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $website_id = get_website_id();
    // if has_strava is checked then redirect to strava auth page redirect 
    if(json_decode($form->form_fields)->$has_strava) {
        $confirmation = [
            'redirectTo'           => 'customUrl',  // or customUrl or customPage
            'messageToShow'        => 'Thank you for your message. We will get in touch with you shortly',
            'customPage'           => '',
            'samePageFormBehavior' => 'hide_form', // or reset_form 
            'customUrl'            => 'http://173.249.200.113:5000/api/strava/auth?website_id='. $website_id .'&api_key=MY_API_KEY&id='.$user_id,
        ];
    }


   // Do your stuffs here 
   return $returnData;
}
add_filter('fluentform/submission_confirmation', 'custom_code_before_confirmation_msg_function', 20, 3);


// Handle user registration form shortcode and include some extrava scripts

function custom_user_registration_form_shortcode($atts) {
    log_to_browser_console("form___id ___", $form_id);

    ob_start();
    $form_id = isset($atts['id']) ? absint($atts['id']) : 0;
    if ($form_id > 0) {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            echo do_shortcode('[fluentform id="' . $form_id . '"]');
        }
        else{
            echo 'You are already logged in!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid form ID';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('user_registeration_form', 'custom_user_registration_form_shortcode');
```

When i recieve confirmation email and i click on confirm registration it takes me to confirmation url and at first it loads json and on reload or when i click the confiramion again it takes me to correct page. The json is in this form

````
{"success":true,"data":{"insert_id":null,"user_inputs":{"first_name":"asadullah","last_name":"jan","email":"myemail@outlook.com","password":"password","confirm_password":"password","age":"20-30","input_radio":"No Team","team":"","dynamic_team":"","state":"AU - NT","state_other":"","input_radio_1":"0"},"has_strava":null,"$api_request_url":"http:\/\/173.249.200.113:5000\/api\/account\/create?first_name=asadullah&last_name=jan&email=asadullah.jan%2Btest14%40outlook.com&age=20-30&state=AU+-+NT&team=&api_key=API_KEY&id=32&website_id=2","user_id":32,"result":{"redirectUrl":"https:\/\/nokia.zing.works","message":"You have been registered successfully."},"error":""}}```

Note that in place of email password and api user gets their email and passowrd.



I did not try anything specific but i did search about it and tired to find the problem but i could not find it. It will be realy helpful if someone can help me with this or give me any helpful docs.
````